# question on existence of open set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

Let $U$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ be an open subset of $U$. Fixed $\epsilon >0$. Does there exist an open set $B \subset U$ such that $B \cap \overline{U} \ne \emptyset$ and $|B \setminus A|< \epsilon$ ?

Comment: I think you should be able to construct a slight fattening $B$ of $A$, so $B$ will meet $\bar{U}$ (it contains $A$). I think this is possible because $A$ is a countable union of open balls, so you can enlarge each ball so that the change in volume is suitable summably small.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $B = A$ does the job, unless $A$ is empty. In that case let $B$ be a small enough ball.

Comment: Ah. Even better. I guess you don't need to enlarge $A$. I wonder if OP really intends $\bar{A}\subset B\subset U$ or something like that? +1 for you.

Comment: Something is amiss, since $B \cap \overline U \not= \emptyset$ doesn't really make sense either, other than to require $B \not= \emptyset$. But that is the question as it was asked.

Comment: Agreed ${}{}{}{}$